# Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and ajax

Tags: .net, ajax

If I set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` in `PageLoad` when I call a codebehind method, I find the culture I set in `PageLoad`, BUT if I call a `[WebMethod]` with `$.ajax()`, the culture is the default one and not the one I had set in `PageLoad`.

I suppose that's because the two calls are in two different threads.

I wonder if there's a way to set the culture so that I find it set in both situations.

Comment: Have you tried setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` at the start of the WebMethod?  The WebMethod is part of a web service, the page is part of the web site--technically two different things hosted in the same service

Comment: This would probably work but at the beginning of the WebMethod I do not know how to set it, I lost the info. In other words I'd need to retrieve what I had set in PageLoad. I'd prefer not to use a cookie...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If different loads of pages can have different culture information; then you might have a problem.  the WebMethod doesn't know which page is using the method (or whether a page used it at all--it's just a web service method, anyone could call it).

I would suggest sending back culture invariant information and then having the page format the information for the culture that it knows about.

Otherwise, you'd probably have to pass the culture information to the web method.

Answer (score -1):

Setting Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture at the start of the WebMethod worked for me